# Recursive function, passing arguments - segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am writing a program for multiplying big numbers using a karatsuba algorithm.
There is a recursive function.
Right before the recursive call I print string values and they are ok. Then, inside this function at the beginning I print the passed arguments again (I should get exactly the same results as before recursive call, earlier printf()) and I get segmentation fault.

This happen not on first function execution, but after many recursive calls.

**My code:**

```
void karatsuba(char *result, char *first, char *second)
{
    printf(" %s    %s\n", first, second);
    <somewhere here conditional return to end recursion>
    ...
    ...
    printf(" %s    %s\n", temp_first, temp_second);
    karatsuba(temp, temp_first, temp_second);
    ...
    ...
}
```

**What do can cause segmentation fault in that case?**

**UPDATE:**

Thank you all for your answers. Stack overflow is propably the reason.
I created a static counter incremented at the start of recursive function and decremented at each of function ends and printed it. At the segmentation fault its value indicated depth of 46778.

Then, I increased stack size as **Graham Borland** pointed to 32MB. Now, counter indicated depth of 159126 calls, so increasing stack size made it better.

**Sum of data in this function is 140B. Multiplying this value by stack depth gives me 21MB, which is less than 32MB.**

After all, this number of recursive calls is too big. Doing calculation on paper I go maximum into <10 recursive calls for my data. Propably infinite recursion. :(

Comment: Make sure you don't get a stack overflow.

Comment: you have to come to the right place with your question - Stack Overflow !!

Comment: Another reason that may cause segmentation fault is if the pointers don't actually point to somewhere meaningful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely to be busting the stack. Depending on the platform, you may be able to increase the stack available to your process. For example, on a Unix-like platform, entering this at the bash prompt before running your program:

```
ulimit -s 32768
```

will increase the stack to 32MB.

Comment: Increasing stack size made my application to make more recursive calls, so stack overflow is propably the reason.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable reason is:
Stack Overflow

Infinite recursion??

Comment: Yes, I think infinite recursion is my problem. Thank you.